# Adding a specific tick to a D3.js axis

Tags: d3.js

I've created an axis with `d3.svg.axis` and a time scale and am happy with the ticks produced by the tick generator. However, I would like to ensure that a particular value is always marked. So for example the if the generator produces the following dates

2000-1-1, 2001-1-1, 2002-1-1, 2003-1-1

I might want to make the axis show

2000-1-1, **2000-7-21**, 2001-1-1, 2002-1-1, 2003-1-1

How do i get an array of the ticks made by the tick generator so that I can add my value and pass it into the `tickValues` function?

I could create a second axis, style it to remove the domain path and pass any additional dates to that ones `tickValues` function but that seems a bit awkward.

Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once you've set up your scale & axis, you can call `ticks()` with no parameters to get the values that it has generated:

```
ticks = myScale.ticks();
```

And then you can push/splice/whatever:

```
ticks.push(some_new_value):
```

And then pass them back into `tickValues`

```
myAxis.tickValues(ticks);
```

Do all this before you .call this axis to add it to the SVG, of course.

Comment: Thankyou! that seems to work fine
I made a quick bl.ock to confirm
http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/aaf0499e139e0b8c58ea

Comment: OK thinking about this the thing that got me was that `scale.ticks(...)` returns an array whilst `axis.ticks(...)` returns the axis object and stores the ticks array for use later. I was suffering from axis/scale confusion