# Adding specific ticks on D3 axis w/ brush

Tags: d3.js

I need help adding specific ticks to an axis that is also being focused with a brush.   I found a similar question/answer for a static axis (without a brush) here:

[Adding a specific tick to a D3.js axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058002/adding-a-specific-tick-to-a-d3-js-axis)

It's along the lines of what I'm trying to do.  My chart is more similar to this example though :

http://blockbuilder.org/pergamonster/419aef09c21ffe8dd1dac971016468d6

Say you wanted to have a 'July 4' tick on both the full axis and the focus axis at all times.  I've tried the axis.ticks().push(...arrayOfNumbers) from the above question/answer in my code, but nothing happens.  If I do axis.tickValues(arrayOfNumbers) it puts ONLY those numbers as ticks, but I would like to have the auto scaling number PLUS my specific numbers on the axis for the focus area.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.  Though my chart is similar the about blockBuilder example, I'm using a linearScale not a timeScale if that matters.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

draw a second x-axis where you only specify the extra ticks.

```
svg.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'x-axis-extra')
   .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickValues([2.78,3.14]));
```

You need a bit of CSS to hide the extra `path`

```
.x-axis-extra path { opacity: 0; }
```

Comment: Good solution, thank you!   Feels like there should be a better way without adding a new component, but this gets the job done.   Thank you.

Comment: I have looked at the d3fc code and with v14 the axis are implemented as such that you don't have control over it despite that it looks like the axis methods are exported through the `chart` but they only store the arguments for the function calls you don't get results back to manipulate the `tickValues`, better would be to create the axis in the chart and use the `xTick*` methods to allow the user to manipulate